# How to get the inreverse selection of a Views query?

Tags: views

Imagine that you can easily create a view that gives you a subset of some content on my site. However, you want the opposite view - all the content minus that subset - and that view is very hard or impossible to create.

The question then becomes: Is it possible to invert the result/selection of a Views query?

NB! Sorting is irrelevant for this question: It's all about the returned selection of items, not the order of the items.

Comment: Can you please give an example what you would like to achieve exactly ? In general you can negate your view filter criteria, for example instead of "Is one of" you could use "Is not one of". You don't need a module for that.

Comment: What I mean is that when i use a view a take some results for example Users.How can I reverse the view so as to show the all the other users from the Users table apart from that I had on my first step?Thansk

Comment: Unless one of the current answers is the correct one, please rephrase and improve the question, so that we can get it answered.

Comment: @Refineo 's comment is also the jist of my responce, I can't see why you don't reverse all your filtering criteria.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. Go back in your Views Settings and find Sort criteria. There you can either reversely sort bu date: Content: Post date (desc) or by alphabetic order. It depends what field you take as sorting criteria.

Comment: Sorry,didn't mean how to reverse the views results,how it is sorted,but only the how to reverse the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

use a "contextual filter" for a field, say userid. At the very bottom click the "more" link and select the "Exclude: If selected, the numbers entered for the filter will be excluded rather than limiting the view" checkbox.

This will revert your filter selection and show all the userids other than the one selected in the filter.

(I'm using D7 with views3).

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but I think it's still very much relevant and I didn't find much about this problem here.

Yes, I think there is a (sandbox) module that solves this problem - [Other View Filter](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/bbinkovitz/2733827). Using that module you first create the view that you want to inverse. Then create a view that displays "everything", and use the first view as a filter in this views (using the "Other View Filter" module). Voila, you have the inverse.

I haven't tested the module myself, but the idea and code looks good.

**Added:** Maybe the (sandbox) module [Views filter view](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/dereine/1443726) is even better?

Answer (score 0):

That's the sandbox version for D7, D8 full release is here https://www.drupal.org/project/other_view_filter